# I have been coding a script that plays a hit animation when an enemy is hit but the enemy gets stuck in frame 1 of the animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code was working as intended until I added the lines defining current health (currentHealth = health;) and (anim.SetTrigger("attacked")) which

I then changed to what you see below to ensure the values were the same as they were not before.

Even after the change I had the same issue, my enemy would get stuck in frame 1 of the hit animation as soon as the game started. Damage and health all work fine so I'm completely stumped as to what could be the problem. Any advice would be appreciated and if needed I can add more info on my code in the comments.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health;
    public float currentHealth;
    private Animator anim;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        currentHealth = 100;
        health = 100;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (health < currentHealth)
            currentHealth = health;
            anim.SetTrigger("attacked");

        if (health <= 0)
            Debug.Log("Enemy is dead");
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing some brackets in your if statements.  
            `anim.SetTrigger("attacked");` is run as it is not a part of the IF block.

Comment: **Use curly braces.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a few problems.  The body of your first guard statement should be enclosed in braces `{` `}` due to having multiple lines logically. The indent is not enough.

Change the lines:

```
if (health < currentHealth)
        currentHealth = health;
        anim.SetTrigger("attacked");
```

...to:

```
if (health < currentHealth)
{ // <--- new
    currentHealth = health;
    anim.SetTrigger("attacked");
} // <--- new
```

Also, you have a typo in the variable names - you want to compare the "current health" to the "maximum".

Change it to read like so:

```
if (currentHealth < health)
```

Going by your code I can't help but feel that you need some flag in your guard statement prior to **playing an animation** (in addition to checking health level), rather than simply going by the health level and *resetting the enemy health to max health each time they are attacked*.  Otherwise, the animation will keep playing from the beginning and never advance.

Let us introduce the flag `_isPlayingAnimation` like so:

```
private bool _isPlayingAnimation;

void Update()
{  
    if (currentHealth < health && !_isPlayingAnimation) // <--- updated
    {
        currentHealth = health;
        anim.SetTrigger("attacked");
        _isPlayingAnimation=true; // <--- new
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

.
.
.
// elsewhere, when the animation completes
_isPlayingAnimation = false; // <--- new
```

### Other tips

Consider renaming your variables. `health` is kinda ambiguous.  Perhaps `maxHealth` would be better?  This will avoid confusion in lines such as the original problem line `health < currentHealth`.

Comment: just IMHO; You are addressing everything but why the animation was running each "Update".  You have not once mentioned that the line for the animation was outside of the scope of the IF block.  That is what the User needs to learn.  This other stuff is excellent but still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Sorceri thanks for pointing that out, I did notice it but I neglected to mention it like you said.  **Updated**. Thanks good sir.

Comment: Nicely explained, particularly the "Other tips". A small note - I think you may have opened a can of worms. You and I would know how to setup an animation trigger or read an animation length to indicate when an animation has stopped playing, but I dare say you've jumped a level of complexity the OP might not be at yet. :)

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful and I appreciate you taking the time to write out this answer. I do still have one problem after updating my code and it's that the hit animation successfully plays and transitions back to idle after I hit it the first time but does not trigger again. The health of the enemy also does not go down on the hit the animation is triggered and I suspect its maybe because I placed the "_isPlayingAnimation = false;" in its own void called animationPlayIsFalse() that only contains that one line. If this is the problem, I'm not sure where i would need to place this line.

Comment: Thanks, by the way I already mentioned _"elsewhere, when the animation completes"._  That should be enough to get you on your way.  Consider accepting this answer. please take note of _["Looks like <refer to original problem> is solved isn't it? As for <refer to "next" problem>, that would be a different question, consider posting it separately."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253829/585968)_

Comment: Thanks! @MickyD I've posted my problem seperately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74402859/after-writing-a-script-for-the-health-and-animations-of-an-enemy-i-have-found-t) and I'd appreciate if you could take a look!